# iOS Universal storyboard on iPhone 5 & 5s issue

Tags: ios, sdk, storyboard

I would like to get some help on how to handle app (storyboard) is set to Universal.

When app run (with a single viewcontroller with a navbar) on a iPhone 5s simulator (with iOS 7.x), a thick black appears on top & bottom
[iPhone 5s with iOS 7.x SDK](http://postimg.org/image/ykpn5us6z/)

[image: iPhone 5s with iOS 7.x SDK]

When switch to iPhone 5.0 with iOS 8.x simulator, no issue.
[iPhone 5s with iOS 8.x SDK](http://postimg.org/image/vwkatxg2x/)

[image: iPhone 5s with iOS 8.x SDK]

Is there any code to fix (remove header & footer) gap in black?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thick black bars on top and bottom (also known as *letterboxing*) are because you have no launch image for the 4-inch screen. Add one. Without this, your app is treated as if it were running on a 4s (3.5-inch screen).